# rxjs6 partition method: Argument of type 'UnaryFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'

Tags: rxjs6

When using Rxjs 6, IDE's report an error while using `partition` method - even though function works fine.

For example: I have this sample code:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, partition } from 'rxjs/operators';

let obs = of(1,2,3,4,6,9,111,13,10,12);

let [a, b] = obs.pipe(
  filter(v => v > 3),
  partition(p => p % 2 == 0)
);

a.subscribe(v => {
  console.log(v);
});

b.subscribe(v => {
  console.log(v);
});
```

The code works fine and separates inputs in odd and even numbers.  However, VSCode and StackBlitz reports an error on the line where `partition` method is called:

> Argument of type 'UnaryFunction,
>   [Observable, Observable]>' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.   Type
>   '[Observable, Observable]' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'.
>       Property '_isScalar' is missing in type '[Observable, Observable]'.

Here is stackblitz URL: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-learn

Comment: See this issue and the issues linked therein: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3807

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on comment posted by [@cartant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6680611/cartant), and the linked [Github issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2995), the correct syntax for calling `partition` is as below:

```
const source = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
const [evens, odds] = partition((val: any) => val % 2 === 0)(source)
```

This removes the error displayed in IDE